# Binary operator '!==' cannot be applied to two 'MyProtocol'

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have created a protocol:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  func doTask()
}
```

Then, I have an array for elements with `MyProtocol` type:

```
var taskList: [MyProtocol] = []
```

Callers can add elements to taskList, eventually, I got an non-empty `taskList`.

Now, I need to have a function that could remove an element from `taskList`, this is what I tried:

```
func removeTask(task: MyProtocol) {
   // Compiler error: Binary operator '!==' cannot be applied to two 'MyProtocol'
   taskList = taskList.filter{$0 !== task}
}
```

But I get compiler error: `Binary operator '!==' cannot be applied to two 'MyProtocol'`

How to get rid of this error?

**=== UPDATE ===**

Thanks @holex, after changed `MyProtocol` to be class-only, it works fine. But now I wonder if I need `MyProtocol` to be not class-only, what would be the solution then?

Comment: make the protocol as a `class` protocol only.

Comment: Thanks @holex, it helps. But now I wonder if I need `MyProtocol` to be not class-only, what would be the solution then?

Comment: The problem is that you perform identity comparison (===) which will not work with non-reference types. That's why the protocol required a class constraint. So the answer is no, you cannot make it work with other types (on its current form)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `!==` operator and not the `!=` operator? Do you actually need reference comparison or do you need value comparison?

Comment: Upvoted @David_Pasztor comment, maybe he or you can answer this *really* stupid question. I've *never* heard of the `!==` operator. A quick search turned up nothing of help. As mentioned, shouldn't this be `!=`? If not, please, can someone define what `!==` means? (I've been programming since, well, it was called that with Assembler/COBOL. Language changes are just that - another form of syntax. But `!==`? Never seen this in almost 40 years!)

Comment: @dfd In Swift, the `===` operator means "these two variables reference the same object." (It's the equivalent of using `==` on objects in ObjC; it doesn't mean they're just equal; it means they reference the same address.) The inverse of `===` is `!==`. While `==` is pronounced "is equal to," `===` is pronounced "is identical to."  See "Identity Operators" https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: Thank you! Very mice explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `!==` which is comparing references. You can't compare `protocol` directly using this operator, since `MyProtocol` can become a `class` or `struct`. Since the `!==` can only compare instances, you must explicitly declare that your `protocol` is a `class`.

Please change the `MyProtocol` to the following, which should fix your problem:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class { // AnyObject can be used here as well
    func doTask()
}
```

Trying to accomplish this without `class` or `AnyObject` will not work with your current design. You might want to implement another comparison method.

Also note that you can try to use `!=` which might be able to do the exact same thing you want. Using this way you don't have to declare `class` or `AnyObject`. So check if that works for you.